# Lua script , this is a key or index?

Tags: lua

```
a = {}
a["key"] = "value"
a[1] = "123"
```

Which one is the index , which one is key? I'm really confuse with this.

Comment: In lua since tables can act as both arrays and dictionaries, key / index are one in the same. You can use any data type as a key/index for a table and by using pairs in a for loop you can get all the key/indexes from the table

Comment: @kingerman88 Thanks! Your explanation is very clear. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 4):

Lua does not differ between `index` and `key`. The manual uses both terms synonymously. Only if they refer to the C API they exclusively use `index` when they talk about integer values.

Among Lua users there is also a tendency to prefer `index` for integers and `key` for anything else.

That's probably because other languages that do not have associative array types use `index` exclusively.

You'll find that the manual and most users will use

`for i, v in ipairs (t) end` where only consecutive integer indices occur and `for k, v in pairs (t) end` where any type of key/index can occur. But of course you can name those variables whatever you want.